# Новые процессоры от AMD Ryzen 5 2400G и Ryzen 3 2200G подвержены уязвимостям Meltdown и Spectre?

Tags: безопасность, железо, процессор, amd

Я смотрел несоклько тестов и про уязвимости в них не было сказано ни слова, на сайте AMD так же 0 информации. С патчами от уязвимостей тоже ничего не понятно - вроде бы выходили обновления для Windows, потом они их советовали откатывать и отключали по умолчанию, потом Intel выпустили секретные патчи для Skylake, а потом нашли ещё 2 новые уязвимости MeltdownPrime и SpectrePrime. И теперь вообще не понятно как определить производительность процессора и почему производителям позволяют продавать по сути опасные вещи.

Comment: >>почему производителям позволяют продавать по сути опасные вещи<< видимо потому что других видимо пока нету, более безопасная архитектура ещё не созрела.

Comment: Как я думаю что когда будут такие безопасные процессоры, то производители на каждом углу будут писать про их безопасность, они рекламной возможностью не могут не воспользоваться.

Comment: С чего бы они были опасными ? Из мухи слона разудли. В 95% случаев эти атаки не несут никакой опасности. Что бы выполнить их на Windows должна быть возможность выполнять произвольный код. А такая возможность есть только в том случае если этот самый код уже попал каким либо образом на вашу систему, а если он попал, то он может сделать и так все что угодно, без всяких Meltdown.

Comment: @Mike Но обновления то всё равно придётся устанавливать - а они отнимут неизвестный % производительности. Никто же не знает сколько % отнимают последние патчи Intel которые были секретно переданы OEM производителям.

Comment: @ОлегУрукхаев Не вижу смысла ставить обновления, которые снижают производительность, если на системе не требуется защиты от этих векторов атак